# why do I get the error 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, icons, undefined

```
export class Medidor {
onUpdateFeature() {
}
id: number;
gas: any;
name: string;
qualification: number;
maxQualification: number; 
}

export default function CircleMeter(props: Medidor) {
const renderMeter = () => {
    let circles = [] as JSX.Element[];

    for (let circle = 1; circle <= props.maxQualification; ++circle) {
        circles.push(<FiCircle
            className={circle <= props.qualification ? 'filled-circle' : 'circle'}
            onClick={() => onCircleClicked(circle)} />);
    }
    circles.push(<input value={props.qualification}></input>)

    return circles;
}
const onCircleClicked = (qualification: number) => {
    const gas = props.gas.copy();
    gas.qualification = qualification;
    props.onUpdateFeature();
}

return <div key={props.gas.id}>
    {props.gas.name}
    <div>{renderMeter()}</div>
</div>
}
```

Im a little lost here, im getting the Cannot read property 'id' of undefined error but i have 0 errors in my vscode. can someone help me understand this a little better? what do I need to declare for my function to recognice the id?

Comment: only `id` is in `props.gas.id` if error then `props.gas` is undefined..... add `key` to `<FiCircle />`

Comment: key={`${props.id}-${circle}`}, i added this and still get the error...

Comment: key is a further, small problem ... your props doesn't contain data

Comment: Im trying to pull the information from a class, but maybe im not doing it correctly... im so confused...

Comment: Properties on your props, or your props object itself, are undefined. Have you tried dropping a `debugger` or `console.log` in your component to examine what your `props` value actually is?

Comment: "Okay, it says `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`, so there must be something that is undefined, but shouldn't. So first, let's _isolate the error_ to see what component or piece of code throws it. Let's put `console.log` throughout the code that executes. If `console.log` didn't show up in console, the error has occurred before `console.log`, if `console.log` show up - error is after it.". After some time of error isolation, you'll end up with a little piece of code that throws. Look what variable's values are, find incorrect ones and understand why they are incorrect in the same way :)